# How to link GLPK with sublime text?

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, linear-programming, glpk

I wanted to solve some Linear programming problems using C++ in sublime text (as I usually code there).

Here is my builder file in sublime Text:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++.exe", "-std=c++17", "${file}",
            "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe",
            "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<input.txt>output.txt"],
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir":"$file_path",
    "selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

I downloaded GLPK package and changed builder file as:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++.exe", "-std=c++17", "${file}",
            "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "-lglpk",
            "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe<input.txt>output.txt"],
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "selector": "source.cpp"
}
```

But it says that glpk can not be found even after setting the system variable path.

```
:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglpk
```

Can someone give steps for setting the glpk to be used with normal C++ code?

Comment: PATH is for executables, not libraries. `-lglpk` looks for `libglpk.a` or `libglpk.dll.a` in some system paths, and in paths specified with `-L`, which you don't have. If I were you, I'd uninstall your GCC, install [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/2752075), install their GCC (yours is heavily outdated anyway, and they ship the latest version), and install GLPK from it as well. Then it will end up in the default search path for `-l`, and `-lglpk` should just work.